# Display last 3 records from database CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Problem with displaying news from database!

**Screenshoot: [image]**

```
Database(table) Articals: ID, Title, Content, User
```

Very simple, i only want display last 3 news from database with foreach in view
(my controller send me array of 3 records in $artical, and this is ok), but view cannot 
display this..
please help me, my dead line is tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cakephp if you put into your tables the field created and modified (DATETIME), the mvc automatically insert the date of creation or when you modify it.

So when  you retrieve your data you can do in this mode

```
$articals = $this->Artical->find('all', array(
  'limit' => 3,
  'order' => 'Artical.created DESC' )
));
```

or in your case if you an increment id you can do in this mode (but I suggest you to use created and insert it into your tables)

```
    $articals = $this->Artical->find('all', array(
          'limit' => 3, 
          'order' => 'Artical.ID DESC' )
        ));
```

If you have some problem to print data try to make a `var_dump($articals)`;
After try to print out your content like this:

```
foreach ($articals as $artical) {
     echo '<p>'.$artical['Artical']['Content'].'</p>';
}
```

Comment: I am modified my table, and added created and modified fields, and
modifed controller and view, but again problem,
in my view i add:
<?php var_dump($articals); ?>
error is:
Notice (8): Undefined variable: articals [APP\View\Articals\show.ctp, line 19]

NULL

when i use foreach like you i have erros:
invalid variable articals 
invalid argument suplied to foreach

Comment: ok, great same error? have you print your array? can you edit your question with the print of the var_dump of your array?

Comment: I think you have to put into your view this : <?php var_dump($artical); ?>

Comment: great, yes Artical :) i have output on screen from my db


:)) what next please,than you so much

Comment: when i use:
<?php var_dump($artical); 
  foreach ($artical as $articals) {
     echo '<p>'.$artical['Artical']['Content'].'</p>';
}
  
  ?>

i have error : Notice (8): Undefined index: Artical [APP\View\Articals\show.ctp, line 21]     :(

Comment: Ok now try to print this foreach ($artical as $articals) { echo '<p>'.$articals['Artical']['Content'].'</p>'; }

Comment: I think that  instead of Content you have to write content

Comment: Accept and vote my answer is the best way to use stackoverflo, if another man have the same problem see your question and see that you have accept that answer it means that this answer can help someone. you are welcome!